# Android - SetBackgroundColor keeps going to blue?

Tags: java, android, colors, rgb

I was just programming away a new app on Android Studio, experimenting with code (I'm new to Java). I was experimenting with Dialogs, and had a Dialog to set the Color of the layout. I had a list of colors and I was using `setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` For example, and even when i set it to use Black or a RGB value, it always just sets the layout color to blue, even when using Color.GREEN or Color.BLACK. Here is the code I am using.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                //Create Alert Dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builder.setTitle("Choose background type");

                builder.setItems(_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
                                builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        //Change colors
                                        switch (which)
                                        {
                                            //Black
                                            case 0:
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                            case 1:
                                            //Blue
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,255));
                                            case 2:
                                            //Brown
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102, 51, 0));
                                            case 3:
                                            //Cyan
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                                            case 4:
                                            //Yellow
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                            case 5:
                                            //Orange
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 128, 0));
                                            case 6:
                                            //Red
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                            case 7:
                                            //Grey
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                            case 8:
                                            //White
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                            case 9:
                                            //Green
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                            case 10:
                                            //Pink
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,51,153));
                                            case 11:
                                            //Cream
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,204,153));
                                            case 12:
                                            //Purple
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(153,0,153));
                                            case 13:
                                            //Sky Blue
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,128,255));
                                            case 14:
                                            //Dark Blue
                                                middleLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,0,153));
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                alert.show();

                            case 1:
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I was also using a CharSequence[] for the color list.

Any Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `break` after each `case`.

Without this, all your cases are executed, with the last one setting the color to blue.